# SXA and local vs reusable datasources in a custom control

Tags: sxa, datasource

In SXA we have components like the Rich Text component that have a version with a local datasource and a reusable version that gets a datasource from a global (site) folder.

This all works fine and I can see local data folders being created and text items appearing in the global site data folders under "Texts".

If I understand correctly the only real difference between the two versions of the RichText component is on creation - the local one doesn't ask anything and creates a local data item, the reusable one does ask for a datasource.

So my question is: how can I use this behavior in my custom rendering? What are the steps I need to take to have a local and reusable version of my custom control?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you will open for example `Sitecore.XA.Feature.PageContent.config` you will see there `<autoDatasourceRenderings>` section.

You can use that section and put there your rendering ID - this will automatically create data source for you.

When local data source will be created, the Data Source field inside of your rendering properties should have something like this: `local:/Data/Text 1`. And under your page item there should be:
[image]

**UPDATE**: In the newer versions of SXA we started to use "Other properties" field in the Experience Accelerator section of the rendering item (it is no longer in the config files):

[image]

Comment: Looks like this is quite different in newer SXA versions.

Comment: @MarkGibbons I updated my answer. In newer versions, those settings have been moved to "Other properties" field on the rendering item.