# How to make a SXA component in the partial design to read data from the current page's local data folder?

Tags: sxa

What exactly needs to be written in the Data source of the partial design such that when the page using this design is previewed, it takes data source from current page's local data folder. I tried some queries like 
`query:./*[@@templateid='{SOME TEMPLATE ID}']` which don't seem to be working here, throwing error. Please help.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at my answer here: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/sxa-and-local-vs-reusable-datasources-in-a-custom-control